# viewpager fragment having SwipeRefreshLayout shows blank page after some duration

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `viewpager` in Activity which has 3 tabs. 
Once I navigate to other activities and after some time come back to this activity, it **shows `blank`** fragment! This happens only on some occasions!

I also noticed **after scrolling over this blank fragment, UI elements gets appeared!** (All fragments has `SwipeRefreshLayout` as a root in xml)

What's solution?

Comment: maybe you didnt wrap the content. The height may match the parent. its hard to say solution without code though :)

Comment: width n height is match_parent